# Android widget setOnClickPendingIntent conflicts with startService

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on a Android widget that displays weather data. The widget has an "update-button" which updates the data when clicked, by starting an IntentService that fetches data from the web and updates the widget. This work just fine, but I would like the widget to also update the data directly when the widget is created, as it is now the user must click the update button on the widget to get data displayed (no data is shown until the "update-button" is clicked).

I have tried starting the IntentService with startService() and that works, but the problem is that the "update-button" on the widget stops working(nothing happens when it is clicked). I can't get these two work together..

Right now I am setting the on click listener for the button and starts the service in the configuration activity(created as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) for the widget. I have also tried broadcasting to the widget (which extends AppWidgetProvider) and that gives me the same problem.

This is the configuration activity class

```
public class WeatherWidgetConfigure extends AppCompatActivity{

    private AppCompatActivity wwc;
    private int widgetID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_widget_configure);
        wwc = this; 

        /*For back press*/
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        /*Get the widget ID from the intent that launched the activity*/
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            widgetID = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }else{
            widgetID = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }


         /*Set listener to ok button*/
        Button okButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*Get value from city spinner*/
                Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
                String cityString = citySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(wwc.getPackageName(), R.layout.weather_widget);

                /*Get updated weather data when update button is clicked*/
                /*Create service intent*/
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(wwc, WeatherService.class);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("city", cityString);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("widgetID", widgetID);
                PendingIntent pendingServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(wwc, widgetID*2, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                /*Attach onClick listener*/
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update_button, pendingServiceIntent);

                // Push update for this widget to the home screen
                AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(wwc);
                manager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, views);


                /*When adding THIS the button listener stops working*/
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(wwc, WeatherService.class);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("city", cityString);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("widgetID", widgetID);
                wwc.startService(serviceIntent);


                /*Create return intent, finish activity*/
                Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the IntentService-class

```
public class WeatherService extends IntentService {


    public WeatherService() {
        super("WeatherService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("Service onHandleIntent");

        try{
            /*Here weather data is catched and saved to the variable wr*/

            /*Set city, start and stop time to widget*/
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.weather_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.city, wr.getCity());
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.start_time, TimeUtils.getHHMM(wr.iterator().next().getStart()));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.stop_time, TimeUtils.getHHMM(wr.iterator().next().getEnd()));
            /*Set weather image to widget*/
            if (Arrays.asList("Klarvær", "Lettskyet", "Delvis skyet").contains(wr.iterator().next().getWeatherName())){
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_fc_icon, R.drawable.sun);
            }
            else if (Arrays.asList("Skyet", "Tåke").contains(wr.iterator().next().getWeatherName())){
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_fc_icon, R.drawable.cloud);
            }
            else if (Arrays.asList("Lette regnbyger", "Regnbyger", "Kraftige regnbyger", "Lette regnbyger og torden", "Regnbyger og torden", "Kraftige regnbyger og torden", "Lette sluddbyger", "Sluddbyger", "Kraftige sluddbyger", "Lette sluddbyger og torden", "Sluddbyger og torden", "Kraftige sluddbyger og torden", "Lett regn", "Regn", "Kraftig regn", "Lett regn og torden", "Regn og torden", "Kraftig regn og torden", "Lett sludd", "Sludd", "Kraftig sludd", "Lett sludd og torden", "Sludd og torden", "Kraftig sludd og torden").contains(wr.iterator().next().getWeatherName())){
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_fc_icon, R.drawable.rain);
            }
            else if (Arrays.asList("Lette snøbyger", "Snøbyger", "Kraftige snøbyger", "Lette snøbyger og torden", "Snøbyger og torden", "Kraftige snøbyger og torden", "Lett snø", "Snø", "Kraftig snø", "Lett snø og torden", "Snø og torden", "Kraftig snø og torden").contains(wr.iterator().next().getWeatherName())){
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_fc_icon, R.drawable.snow);
            }
            else{
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_fc_icon, R.drawable.star);
            }

            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            int currentWidgetID = intent.getIntExtra("widgetID", -1);
            manager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetID, views);

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the widget class

```
public class WeatherWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        System.out.println("ONUPDATE CALLED");

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried building your RemoteViews layout inside of your intentService?  That way you will be able to call `setOnClickPendingIntent` on your views and they will be handled.

Comment: that worked, thanks!